# Changing loop to organize and reduce XML output

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML output that is given to me that looks like this:

```
        <lsar030><head></head><body><group1></group1><Part></part><national_stock_number_cross_reference>
            <federal_supply_classification>5310</federal_supply_classification>
            <national_item_identification_number>008805978</national_item_identification_number>
            <figure_number>700</figure_number>
            <item_number>34</item_number>
        </national_stock_number_cross_reference>
        <national_stock_number_cross_reference>
            <federal_supply_classification>5310</federal_supply_classification>
            <national_item_identification_number>008805978</national_item_identification_number>
            <figure_number>701</figure_number>
            <item_number>10</item_number>
        </national_stock_number_cross_reference>
        <national_stock_number_cross_reference>
            <federal_supply_classification>5310</federal_supply_classification>
            <national_item_identification_number>008805978</national_item_identification_number>
            <figure_number>703</figure_number>
            <item_number>9</item_number>
        </national_stock_number_cross_reference></body></lsar030>
```

I made a basic code using `xml.etree.cElementTree` to organize the data and remove duplicate `<federal_supply_classification>` and `<national_item_identification_number>` information.

```
             for national_stock_number_cross_reference in body.findall('./' + junk + 'national_stock_number_cross_reference'):
                fsc = national_stock_number_cross_reference.find('./' + junk + 'federal_supply_classification').text
                niin = national_stock_number_cross_reference.find('./' + junk + 'national_item_identification_number').text
                nsn = fsc+niin
                if nsn in nsnList:
                    pass
                else:
                    nsnList.append(nsn)
            nsnList.sort()
            for nsn in nsnList:
                fsc = str(nsn[0:4])
                niin = str(nsn[4:])
                repeat = False
                for national_stock_number_cross_reference in body.findall('./' + junk + 'national_stock_number_cross_reference'):

                    tabs = 3
                    figure_number = (national_stock_number_cross_reference.find('./' + junk + 'figure_number').text)
                    item_number = (int(national_stock_number_cross_reference.find('./' + junk + 'item_number').text))
                    if national_stock_number_cross_reference.find('./' + junk + 'federal_supply_classification').text == fsc:
                        if national_stock_number_cross_reference.find('./' + junk + 'national_item_identification_number').text == niin:
                            nsnIndexXml += '<nsnindxrow>\n'
                            if repeat == False:
                                nsnIndexXml += self.getNSNCode(fsc, niin, tabs)
                                repeat = True
                            else:
                                nsnIndexXml += self.getNSNCode('', '', tabs)                            
                            if figure_number[0].isnumeric:
                                figure_number = 'fig' + figure_number
                            nsnIndexXml += '<callout assocfig="%s" label="%i">\n' % (figure_number, item_number)    
                            nsnIndexXml += '</nsnindxrow>\n'
            nsnIndexXml += '</nsnindx>\n'
            nsnIndexXml += '</nsnindxwp>'
```

My output ends up looking like this:

```
<nsnindxrow>
<nsn>
<fsc>5310</fsc>
<niin>00-880-5978</niin>
</nsn>
<callout assocfig="fig700" label="34">
</nsnindxrow>
<nsnindxrow>
<nsn>
<fsc></fsc>
<niin></niin>
</nsn>
<callout assocfig="fig701" label="10">
</nsnindxrow>
<nsnindxrow>
<nsn>
<fsc></fsc>
<niin></niin>
</nsn>
<callout assocfig="fig703" label="9">
</nsnindxrow>
```

When I need to end with an output that looks like this.

```
<nsnindxrow>
<nsn>
<fsc>5310</fsc>
<niin>00-880-5978</niin>
</nsn>
<callout assocfig="fig700" label="34">
<callout assocfig="fig701" label="10">
<callout assocfig="fig703" label="9">
</nsnindxrow>
```

Is there a simple way I can add in a find and remove to the code or do I need to adjust my loop statement? and how?

Comment: @slybloty

Do you mean to move 
                          `if repeat == False:
                                nsnIndexXml += self.getNSNCode(fsc, niin, tabs)
                                repeat = True
                            else:
                                nsnIndexXml += self.getNSNCode('', '', tabs)`

outside of the "for" loop? I am unsure how to do that without screwing up the output. Could you show me what you mean exactly?
I was wondering if I can just change the "else" statement to just skip putting in an NSN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me in suggesting another approach but consider an XSLT solution as your needs is the classic [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) involving grouping on the `<federal_supply_classification>` and `<national_item_identification_number>` pairing. As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (part of the Extensible Stylesheet Language Family which includes XPath) is a special-purpose declarative language designed specifically to transform XML documents to various end use structures.

Python's [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module can run XSLT 1.0 scripts and also call external processors such as [Saxon/Xalan](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) or PowerShell/Bash at command line. In this approach, you avoid any general purpose looping or conditional logic or even string concatenation of elements. Finally, XSLT is a well-formed XML file and so can be parsed from file or string like any other XML document.

Below examples wraps your posted XML sample in root tags: `<root>...</root>`. Change *root* in first template of XSLT to actual XML root.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl to be referenced below)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="numkey" match="national_stock_number_cross_reference"
          use="concat(federal_supply_classification, national_item_identification_number)"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="national_stock_number_cross_reference[generate-id() =
           generate-id(key('numkey', concat(federal_supply_classification, national_item_identification_number))[1])]"/>    
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="national_stock_number_cross_reference">
  <nsnindxrow>
    <nsn> 
      <fsc><xsl:value-of select="federal_supply_classification"/></fsc>
      <niin><xsl:value-of select="national_item_identification_number"/></niin>
    </nsn>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('numkey', concat(federal_supply_classification, national_item_identification_number))">
      <callout>
        <xsl:attribute name="assocfig"><xsl:value-of select="concat('fig', figure_number)"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="label"><xsl:value-of select="item_number"/></xsl:attribute>
      </callout>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </nsnindxrow>  
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** Script

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM SOURCE
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(newdom)

# OUTPUT TRANSFORMED TREE TO STRING
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True,  xml_declaration=True)

# OUTPUT STRING TO FILE
xmlfile = open('Output.xml', 'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<nsnindxrow>
  <nsn>
    <fsc>5310</fsc>
    <niin>008805978</niin>
  </nsn>
  <callout assocfig="fig700" label="34"/>
  <callout assocfig="fig701" label="10"/>
  <callout assocfig="fig703" label="9"/>
</nsnindxrow>
```

Comment: I get this error. any idea why?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1116484\Desktop\nsnindex.py", line 17, in <module>
    xmlfile.write(tree_out)
TypeError: 'NoneType' does not support the buffer interface
>>>

Comment: Lxml.etree is returning an empty transformed result, likely because XSLT is not matching tags correctly. In your post, you do not include a root tag. What is it? As mentioned I used a generic `<root>`. Replace actual with this *root* tag in the .xsl file specifically at `<xsl:template match="root"/>`.

Comment: The root tag is <national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>

but I am still getting the error message.

Comment: Sorry, I can't recreate that error. I just copied over both .xsl and .py scripts in this answer and using your example posted .xml, the desired output renders. Possibly your actual .xml differs from posted snippet.

Comment: Could it be because I do not have any XSLT development tools installed on my computer, like Xalan?

Comment: You need python's [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module which comes with an XSLT processor, specifically [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/). Try running this answer with the XML you posted (include root tag). Come to think of it you may have namespace issue. Please edit your post with full header and root tag including all `xmlns` items.

Comment: I UPDATED MY wheel and lxml library and changed to the original output that I gave and that you used to develop the xlst and I get this error:

"File "C:\Users\1116484\Desktop\nsnindex.py", line 4, in <module>
    dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')
  File "src\lxml\lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:78770)

Comment: File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1793, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:114611)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1819, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:114958)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1723, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:113870)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1126, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:108617)

Comment: File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 584, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:102153)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 694, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103803)
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 624, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:102715)
  File "<string>", line None
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 7, column 9"

Comment: I get the same error when no root tag is included just as you originally posted. See how important that root tag is? Wrap entire post with `<root>...</root>` tags. If you want to use `<national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>`, be sure to replace **root** in XSLT script at `<xsl:template match="root">`.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right about it working for the given input  but when I change the root tag to national_stock_number_cross_reference_index and change the dom - RT.parse to 'lsar030.xml' instead of input.xml. I get the same error message.

 nsnindex.py, line 17, in <module>
    xmlfile.write(tree_out)
TypeError: 'NoneType' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: xml file is as follows:
'<lsar030>
    <head></head>
    <body>
           <group1></group1>
           <Parts></Parts>
<national_stock_number_cross_reference_index></national_stock_number_cross_reference_index></body></lsar030>'

Do I need to write something to ignore the other tagged groups and to only look at the <national_stock_number_cross_reference_index> section?

Comment: I am going to say this worked for the initial issue and will open a second question for the next portion.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `<nsnindxrow>` tag every time you cycle through the `national_stock_number_cross_reference` items (3rd `for` loop):

```
for national_stock_number_cross_reference in body.findall('./' + junk + 'national_stock_number_cross_reference'):
```

The first time it goes through the `for` loop it creates the `<nsn>` tag because `repeat` is false. Then `repeat` gets switched to `true` therefore it places an empty tag the next time it goes through. It does this for all the different `federal_supply_classification` items you have, 3 in this case.

You need to move the `<nsn>` tag create procedure before this loop in order to avoid recreating it every single time.