# TypeError: 'NoneType' does not support the buffer interface: when Transforming XML using XSLT

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, nonetype

Related to [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248286/changing-loop-to-organize-and-reduce-xml-output), I want to thank @Parfait for helping me develop an XSLT foundation for my project with the current XSLT code being used. However I am getting an error when I run the python Module it says.

```
File "nsnindex.py", line 17, in <module>
  xmlfile.write(tree_out)
TypeError: 'NoneType' does not support the buffer interface.
```

The overall plan is for XPATH to go straight to the third child node

```
<national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>
```

and use the data in that section to output to a new file. At the moment, python spits out all of the data in one blob, without tags, and gives me the error above.

## XML Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<lsar030 xsi:schemaLocation="places" xmlns="place2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>
        <requester>Guy</requester>
        <time>12:23:44 PM</time>
        <date>Aug 2, 2016</date>
        <eiac>ABC</eiac>
        <item_name>Thing</item_name>
        <start_lcn>start34</start_lcn>
        <alc>00</alc>
        <lcn_type>P</lcn_type>
        <stop_lcn>AA01AA13AB</stop_lcn>
        <useable_on_code>ABC</useable_on_code>
        <technical_manual_code>000</technical_manual_code>
        <technical_manual_number>15241</technical_manual_number>
        <report_format>STUFF</report_format>
        <kit_option>45</kit_option>
        <part_number_cross_reference_index>true</part_number_cross_reference_index>
        <national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>true</national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>
        <reference_designation_cross_reference_index>false</reference_designation_cross_reference_index>
        <figure_item_number_cross_reference_index>false</figure_item_number_cross_reference_index>
        <include_drawings_in_output>No</include_drawings_in_output>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 204</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 205</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 208</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 207</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>11</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header> FIGURE 501 </header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>12</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 505</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 201</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 202</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 203/header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 200</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>865/technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 503</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>865</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 502</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>865</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 504</header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
            <section>2</section>
            <technical_manual_functional_group_code>132</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
            <header>FIGURE 206/header>
        </technical_manual_functional_group_code_header>
        <baseline_comparison>false</baseline_comparison>
        <usmc_option>No</usmc_option>
    </head>
    <body>
        <repair_parts_list>
            <repair_parts_fgc_group>             
                <repair_part>
                    <item_number>1</item_number>
                    <smr>PAFDD</smr>
                    <cage_code>53711</cage_code>
                    <reference_number>7102539</reference_number>
                    <technical_manual_indenture_code>1</technical_manual_indenture_code>
                    <item_name>DINGLE</item_name>
                    <useable_on_code>EAU</useable_on_code>
                    <fully_effective>true</fully_effective>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <qpei>1</qpei>
                    <figure_number>101</figure_number>
                    <technical_manual_functional_group_code>0000000000A</technical_manual_functional_group_code>
                    <federal_supply_classification>1234</federal_supply_classification>
                    <national_item_identification_number>000000000</national_item_identification_number>
                    <system_or_end_item_provisioning_contract_control_number>A1ABC</system_or_end_item_provisioning_contract_control_number>
                    <plisn>ABCD</plisn>
                    <effectivity_flag>false</effectivity_flag>
                    <effectivity_label>BERRY</effectivity_label>
                </repair_part>
            </repair_parts_fgc_group>
        </repair_parts_list>
        <part_number_cross_reference_index>
            <work_package_sequence_number>0005</work_package_sequence_number>
            <part_number_cross_reference>
                <reference_number>XXXXXX</reference_number>
                <figure_number>1</figure_number>
                <item_number>10</item_number>
            </part_number_cross_reference>
        </part_number_cross_reference_index>
        <national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>
            <work_package_sequence_number>0001</work_package_sequence_number>
            <national_stock_number_cross_reference>
                <federal_supply_classification>1234</federal_supply_classification>
                <national_item_identification_number>000000000</national_item_identification_number>
                <figure_number>1</figure_number>
                <item_number>1</item_number>
            </national_stock_number_cross_reference><national_stock_number_cross_reference>
                <federal_supply_classification>1234</federal_supply_classification>
                <national_item_identification_number>000000000</national_item_identification_number>
                <figure_number>2</figure_number>
                <item_number>4</item_number>
            </national_stock_number_cross_reference><national_stock_number_cross_reference>
                <federal_supply_classification>1234</federal_supply_classification>
                <national_item_identification_number>000000000</national_item_identification_number>
                <figure_number>3</figure_number>
                <item_number>2</item_number>
            </national_stock_number_cross_reference><national_stock_number_cross_reference>
                <federal_supply_classification>1235</federal_supply_classification>
                <national_item_identification_number>111111111</national_item_identification_number>
                <figure_number>1</figure_number>
                <item_number>1</item_number>
            </national_stock_number_cross_reference><national_stock_number_cross_reference>
                <federal_supply_classification>1235</federal_supply_classification>
                <national_item_identification_number>111111111</national_item_identification_number>
                <figure_number>2</figure_number>
                <item_number>3</item_number>
            </national_stock_number_cross_reference>
        </national_stock_number_cross_reference_index><national_stock_number_cross_reference>
                <federal_supply_classification>1236</federal_supply_classification>
                <national_item_identification_number>212121212</national_item_identification_number>
                <figure_number>2</figure_number>
                <item_number>3</item_number>
            </national_stock_number_cross_reference>
        </national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>
    </body>
</lsar030>
```

## XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="numkey" match="lsar030/body/national_stock_number_cross_reference_index/national_stock_number_cross_reference"
          use="concat(federal_supply_classification, national_item_identification_number)"/>

  <xsl:template match="lsar030/body/national_stock_number_cross_reference_index">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="national_stock_number_cross_reference[generate-id() =
           generate-id(key('numkey', concat(federal_supply_classification, national_item_identification_number))[1])]"/>    
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lsar030/body/national_stock_number_cross_reference_index/national_stock_number_cross_reference">
  <nsnindxrow>
    <nsn> 
      <fsc><xsl:value-of select="federal_supply_classification"/></fsc>
      <niin><xsl:value-of select="national_item_identification_number"/></niin>
    </nsn>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('numkey', concat(federal_supply_classification, national_item_identification_number))">
      <callout>
        <xsl:attribute name="assocfig"><xsl:value-of select="concat('fig', figure_number)"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="label"><xsl:value-of select="item_number"/></xsl:attribute>
      </callout>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </nsnindxrow>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Python Code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
dom = ET.parse('lsar030.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM SOURCE
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(newdom)

# OUTPUT TRANSFORMED TREE TO STRING
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

# OUTPUT STRING TO FILE
xmlfile = open('Output.xml', 'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

## OUTPUT

```
<nsnindxrow>
<nsn>
<fsc>5310</fsc>
<niin>00-880-5978</niin>
</nsn>
<callout assocfig="fig700" label="34">
<callout assocfig="fig701" label="10">
<callout assocfig="fig703" label="9">
</nsnindxrow>
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? is it my XPATH? @Parfait 's program worked when the root tag was just `<national_stock_number_cross_reference_index>`, but it stopped working properly once I changed the path to match the more complex file.

Comment: Much fuller better example XML file and as I thought you have an undefined namespace prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues in XML emerge affecting the XSLT transformation:

1. An undeclared namespace prefix (`xmlns="place2"`) where the *xmlns* special attribute in header does not have a colon separated identifier. Therefore, XSLT must declare a prefix.
2. Additional element levels where parent nodes and their siblings above
   `national_stock_number_cross_reference_index` element must be parsed out. Therefore, XSLT must use additional templates.

Consider following adjusted XSLT, declaring a `doc` prefix which is prefixed in all other XPath expressions. Use same Python code to process.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="place2" exclude-result-prefixes="doc">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="numkey" match="doc:national_stock_number_cross_reference"
          use="concat(doc:federal_supply_classification, doc:national_item_identification_number)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/doc:lsar030">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:head"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates seect="doc:body"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:head"/>

  <xsl:template match="doc:body">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:national_stock_number_cross_reference_index"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:national_stock_number_cross_reference_index">  
    <nsnindxrows>  
      <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:national_stock_number_cross_reference[generate-id() =
           generate-id(key('numkey', concat(doc:federal_supply_classification, doc:national_item_identification_number))[1])]"/>    
    <nsnindxrows>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="doc:national_stock_number_cross_reference">
  <nsnindxrow>
    <nsn> 
      <fsc><xsl:value-of select="doc:federal_supply_classification"/></fsc>
      <niin><xsl:value-of select="doc:national_item_identification_number"/></niin>
    </nsn>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('numkey', concat(doc:federal_supply_classification, doc:national_item_identification_number))">
      <callout>
        <xsl:attribute name="assocfig"><xsl:value-of select="concat('fig', doc:figure_number)"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="label"><xsl:value-of select="doc:item_number"/></xsl:attribute>
      </callout>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </nsnindxrow>  
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

*(unlike earlier question's XML, only one callout renders due to this XML's one pairing of `<federal_supply_classification>` and `<national_item_identification_number>`)*.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nsnindxrows>
  <nsnindxrow>
    <nsn>
      <fsc>1234</fsc>
      <niin>000000000</niin>
    </nsn>
    <callout assocfig="fig1" label="1"/>
    <callout assocfig="fig2" label="4"/>
    <callout assocfig="fig3" label="2"/>
  </nsnindxrow>
  <nsnindxrow>
    <nsn>
      <fsc>1235</fsc>
      <niin>111111111</niin>
    </nsn>
    <callout assocfig="fig1" label="1"/>
    <callout assocfig="fig2" label="3"/>
  </nsnindxrow>
  <nsnindxrow>
    <nsn>
      <fsc>1236</fsc>
      <niin>212121212</niin>
    </nsn>
    <callout assocfig="fig2" label="3"/>
  </nsnindxrow>
</nsnindxrows>
```

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help. And in the future, always post the top header of sample XML including the header lines and root tags as they carry important info.

Comment: Is there a reason why the xslt still spits out the information in the header location. It does not do it on the given input because I removed data. However, when the tags are filled out. The top of the output has all of the header information. I might use some of that info later but what should I start tinkering with for the header info to go away?

Comment: I am not understanding. What tags? What header? This: `<?xml version="1.0"?>`? Again, if you are using a different XML in any way than what is posted here, the XSLT may not work the same.

Comment: My mistake. the output doesn't show any of that. However, My python shell shows all of the <nsnindxrow>'s in the file but the output file is only writing the first line.

I will adjust the input to include more lines of the nsnindex

Comment: See updated XSLT, where I add a root to the output: `<nsnindxrows>...<nsnindxrows>`.

Comment: I changed to    '<nsnindxrow>...</nsnindxrow>' because I was getting errors.

I did notice that the output is using the '    <head>' info. So, I have added to the input.
I am new to XSLT so I assumed that the script would ignore the '    <head>' info and go straight to the info of the body, but I guess that was to much assumption.

Comment: Forgive me but you are constantly updating your XML which necessitates an updated XSLT. See update with revised `<head>` tag. And try modifying as best you can to your actual XML. Read online tutorials if needed. XSLT is not an easy language, recursive in nature in function form, and not object-oriented like Python.

Comment: And again, if you change the structure of XML in any way, this XSLT may yield a different result. Also note you have broken tags issue in your posting which does not render well-formed XML. This XSLT uses corrected version